# javascript parsing

Tags: javascript

i have this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //<![CDATA[  
    var who;

    FB_RequireFeatures(["Api"], function(){ 

        var who = api.get_session().uid;
        alert(who);

        });

        alert("the uid is: "+who);

    //]]> 
});
```

the problem:
the code outside the FB_RequireFeatures block is executing before the one inside it.
due to which the value of `who` is coming out to be undefined.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FB_RequireFeatures` function appears to be making an asynchronous call, so you're not doing anything wrong, that's just the way it works - the alert is called before the request comes back.

You must design your code in a way that the code that depends on the result of the `FB_RequireFeatures` functions are called only after the request completes. You can call another function inside the callback, for example:

```
var who;

$(document).ready(function() {        
    FB_RequireFeatures(["Api"], function() {
        who = api.get_session().uid;
        doSomeOtherStuff();
    });
});

function doSomeOtherStuff() {
    alert("the uid is: " + who);
}
```

Now the `doSomeOtherStuff` function is called only after the `FB_RequireFeatures` function finishes, and you should do all following code inside the `doSomeOtherStuff` function – which you can name to be anything you want, obviously.

I moved the `who` variable out of the ready block to keep it in scope for the `doSomeOtherStuff` function, and removed the `var` from the inner function so that you're referencing the original variable instead of creating a new one, otherwise it's the same.

Comment: how to make sure the code that follows the function gets executed after FB_RequireFeatures is done requesting?

Comment: that does help things a bit. but can something be done to make the code after the FB_RequireFeatures to wait explicitly for FB_requireFeatures to finish?

Comment: i tried the above method. for some reason the code in someotherfunction() is still getting executed before the ajax call completes?

Comment: @amit: no, you can't turn asynchronous execution code into synchronous or vice-versa. All code you want to run when `FB_RequiresFeatures` has finished must be passed to it as a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a new local `who` variable. Remove the `var` from the place where you set who. Also, you can't reference `who` until the callback to the FB_RequireFeatures function is run.